# ListView: should open a new activity

Tags: android, arrays, string, listview

Hello, Everybody. I'm a newbie. My goal is when I want to click on a specific item from the ListView, it should open a new activity that I've programmed. For example: when I click on "John", I wish it opens a class called X, Mary, should open a class Y, Charlie, class Z, so on. I've tried using a "onListItemClick" code at the end of the code, but it doesn't work. Nothing happens when I click on John's name from ListView app. Please, where my code is wrong and help me where I should put the code and what the correct code is.

P.S: I declared all activities on Manifest file

This is my code that I'm using:

```
public class Searchsort extends Activity {

    private ListView lv1;
    private EditText ed;
    private String lv_arr[]={"John","Mary","Carl","Rose","Charlie","Allan", "João"};
    private ArrayList<String> arr_sort= new ArrayList<String>();
    int textlength=0;

    /** Called when the activity is first created. */
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle icicle) {
        super.onCreate(icicle);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);
        lv1 = (ListView)findViewById(R.id.ListView01);
        ed = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.EditText01);

        // By using setAdpater method in listview we an add string array in list.

        lv1.setAdapter(new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1 ,   lv_arr));
        ed.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {

            public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {

            }

            public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count, int after) {

            }

            public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) {
                textlength=ed.getText().length();
                arr_sort.clear();
                for(int i=0;i<lv_arr.length;i++) {
                    if(textlength<=lv_arr[i].length()) {
                        if(ed.getText().toString().equalsIgnoreCase((String) lv_arr[i].subSequence(0,  textlength))) {
                            arr_sort.add(lv_arr[i]);
                        }
                    }
                }

                lv1.setAdapter(new ArrayAdapter<String>  (Searchsort.this,android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1 , arr_sort));

            }
        });
    }

    public void onListItemClick(ListView parent, View v, int position, long id) {
        if ("John".equals(lv_arr[position])) { 
            Intent myIntent = new Intent(Searchsort.this, X.class);
            startActivity(myIntent);

        if ("Mary".equals(lv_arr[position])) { 
            Intent myIntent = new Intent(Searchsort.this, Y.class);
            startActivity(myIntent);

        if ("Charlie".equals(lv_arr[position])) { 
            Intent myIntent = new Intent(Searchsort.this, W.class);
            startActivity(myIntent);


        }
    }

}
```

Answer (score 1):

The only way to override the onListItemClick method is if your Activity extends ListActivity. Since it does not, you will have to move your code in your onListItemClick method into the appropriate method within your setting of the item click listener

```
lv1.setOnItemClickListener(new onItemClickListener(){

    @Override
    protected void onListItemClick(AdapterView<?> arg0, View view, int position, long id){
        // Your code
    }
});
```

FYI, this is a similar question asked several times on Stack.

Answer (score 0):

```
listView1.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {
    public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> arg0, View arg1, int position,long arg3) {
        Toast.makeText(cxt, "You select Item " + (position + 1), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();    
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this code..

```
listView.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> paramAdapterView, View paramView, int paramInt,
            long paramLong) {
        switch( position )
{
   case 0:  Intent newActivity0 = new Intent(YourActivity.this, second.class);     
            startActivity(newActivity0);
            break;
   case 1:  Intent newActivity1 = new Intent(YourActivity.this, third.class);     
            startActivity(newActivity1);
            break;
   case 2:  Intent newActivity2 = new Intent(YourActivity.this, fourth.class);     
            startActivity(newActivity2);
            break;
   case 3:  Intent newActivity3 = new Intent(YourActivity.this, fifth.class);     
            startActivity(newActivity3);
            break;
   case 4:  Intent newActivity4 = new Intent(YourActivity.this, sixth.class);     
            startActivity(newActivity4);
            break;
}              
    }
});
```

Try and let me know...Hope this helps you :-)